# Why \caption conflicts with beamer?

Tags: beamer, captions

I am attempting to use package `caption` with `beamer`. The MWE below runs fine. If I uncomment `captionof`, I am presented with message `you cannot use '\unskip' in vertical mode`. To be even more enigmatic, if I change to document class memoir, even with `captionof` compiles fine. What is going on here?

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
    %\documentclass{memoir}

    \usepackage{listingsutf8}   % Use program listings
    \usepackage{caption}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\SourceFileBad[4][]{
        \lstinputlisting{#2}
    %   \captionof{lstlisting}{#3}%
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \SourceFileBad {sumvec.c}{The file}{lst:sumvec.c}
    \end{document}

    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % The sumvec file, for completeness
    int sumvec(int v[N])
    {
        int i, sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) longer line to test
          sum += v[i];
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Beamer is is very own thing so you really should not expect it to work with packages that change core stuff. Why do you want to use the caption package with beamer in the first place?

Comment: Btw listing already have a caption option build in.

Comment: Is the built-in option compatible with babel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any conflict, you just have to use a `frame` environment:

```
\begin{frame}
\SourceFileBad{sumvec.c}{The file}{lst:sumvec.c}
\end{frame}
```

Full MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{sumvec.c}
int sumvec(int v[N])
{
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) longer line to test
      sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}   
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\SourceFileBad[4][]{
    \lstinputlisting{#2}
   \captionof{lstlisting}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\SourceFileBad{sumvec.c}{The file}{lst:sumvec.c}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]